# Create category/subcategory of "places" with Android preferences

Tags: android, preferences

I'm trying to code a PreferenceList from value arrays that has categories and sub-categories that look something like this:

**All**

**Category 1**

Sub-category 1.1

Sub-category 1.2

Sub-category 1.3

Sub-category 1.4

**Category 2**

Sub-category 2.1

Sub-category 2.2

I want the items with bold font to be categories, and the rest subcategories, and restrict the user to select only one of the items displayed, but I've failed  miserably on trying to code it or search for an answer. Does someone have and idea on how to make this possible? Just a simple example would suffice.

Note: It has to work from API 8 to the latest (KitKat).

Thanks in advance!